# Youtube brand account cannot use an internal youtube API-client

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-oauth

I've created an internal app in the google cloud console for uploading videos with an application.

When choosing the youtube channel (brand account) for authentication, I get a `403: org_internal`. If I choose my *"personal"* account, I get a working token.

I also tried the `OnBehalfOfContentOwner` and `OnBehalfOfContentOwnerChannel` parameters which resulted in either the same behaviour or a `googleapi: Error 403: Access forbidden. The request may not be properly authorized., forbidden` response

I have verified that:

- I am using G-Suite
- the cloud app is bound to the organisation
- the channel was created by an organisation-account
- the *"primary owner"* of the youtube channel is in the organisation

I would like to know how to use a youtube brand account in combination with an internal cloud api client accessing the `youtube.upload` scope or if making it external (which I do not want) is the only option.

Edit/Note: There is only one account in the organisation which is me.

Comment: I would contact your account manager they can help you.

Comment: I have added the note that there is no extra account manager involved. I am the account manager and there is only one account in the organisation.

Comment: I ran into this same issue.  I can authorize my corporate account, but not the branded account that the company created.  I guess you have to have external oauth client for this to work?

Comment: Did you have any luck figuring this out? I'm also currently trying to use an internal app to manage an associated brand account and running into the same issues. Thanks